# Problema input com validação

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho um form no php aonde tenho alguns campos (input) e um botão submit para enviar. Um dos inputs faço a verificação em javascript se tem ou não link igual, se tem link igual ele não deveria deixar o botão salvar. Só que quando clico no botão enviar ele envia o form mesmo assim. Quero que quando a validação do link estiver errada ele não envie, preciso fazer com que após a validação ele deixe ou não salvar.

Segue abaixo meu código do javascript aonde no ajax coloco uma validação:

```
function repeatLink(){

    var link = $("#link").val();


    if (link === null || link === '') {
        $("#link").addClass("input-required");
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: './model/functions/link_repeat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {link: link},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === 'true') {
                $("#link").addClass("input-required");
                $("#alert-link").append("<span style='color:red'><b>Esse link já existe! Escolha outro!</b></span>"); 
                return false;
            }
            $("#more").submit() 
        }
    });
}



$link = $_POST['link'];

        $stmtLink = $conn->prepare("SELECT link FROM menu WHERE link LIKE :link");
        $stmtLink->bindValue(':link', $link);

       if($stmtLink->execute() && $stmtLink->rowCount() > 0){
        echo 'true';
       }else{
           echo'false';
       }
```

Comment: Você verificou o valor retornado do ajax no `data` ?

Comment: Sim, está retornando true ou false. Se retorna true cai na minha validação no javascript.

Comment: O que acontece na verdade é, se a pessoa digitar no meu input um link que já existe em meu banco de dados vai retornar true, ou seja cair na minha validação do javascript. Quando isso acontecer for true, não deve prosseguir. Ou seja, dar o submit no form.

Comment: Ana, talvez haja algum caractere extra no URL. Estou confuso porque isso não funciona, mas o echo no PHP podia ter sido facilmente feito com `echo ($stmtLink->execute() && $stmtLink->rowCount() > 0)`

Comment: ahh entendi, coloca depois do `data: {link: link}` => `async: false,`.

Comment: @FlavioMisawa Pode explicar o porquê de usar uma requisição síncrona?

Comment: Preciso só fazer que minha validação seja usada pelo botão que envio não é?

Comment: Post o HTML do botão que você chama essa function também. Talvez o problema esteja ali.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaRibeiro em que momento essa função é chamada ? Pode colocar o trecho do form, onde chama a função ?

Answer (score 2):

**Tente**

```
function repeatLink(){

    var link = $("#link").val();


    if (link === null || link === '') {
        $("#link").addClass("input-required");
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: './model/functions/link_repeat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {link: link},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'existe') {
                $("#link").addClass("input-required");
                $("#alert-link").append("<span style='color:red'><b>Esse link já existe! Escolha outro!</b></span>"); 
                return false;
            }else{
            $("#more").submit() ;
            }
        }
    });
}



$link = $_POST['link'];

$stmtLink = $conn->prepare("SELECT link FROM menu WHERE link = :link");
$stmtLink->bindValue(':link', $link);

$stmtLink->execute();

if($stmtLink->rowCount() > 0){
echo 'existe';
}else{
echo'nao_existe';
}
```

Comment: Você só mudou a resposta ao lado do servidor. E por que retornar exatamente `false` se já tem o statement `else` no JavaScript?

Comment: Você poderia ter feito isso de um comentário então